# setup:upgrade and setup:di:compile not working

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.1

I've been trying for a few days, but I never could.

I installed Magento 2.1.

I installed the theme and then modules activated via ssh (bin/magento).

Then bin/magento setup:upgrade and bin/magento setup:di:compile I'm getting some errors.

I’m using Plesk Onyx 17.8 on Centos 7

I’m using PHP 7.0.33 for Magento 2.1 on webserver.

PHP cli Version

```
-bash-4.2$ php -v
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Oct 30 2018 19:30:51) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v10.0.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by ionCube Ltd.
-bash-4.2$
```

magento setup:upgrade output

```
-bash-4.2$ cd bin

-bash-4.2$ ./magento setup:upgrade
Magento supports PHP 5.6, 7.0.2, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html

-bash-4.2$
```

Setup:upgrade output

```
-bash-4.2$ /opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php bin/magento setup:upgrade -vvv


  [ReflectionException]                                                            
  Class Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Converter\Interceptor does not exist  



Exception trace:
 () at /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:19
 ReflectionClass->__construct() at /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:19
...
...
...
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/bin/magento:23


setup:upgrade [--keep-generated] [--magento-init-params="..."]


-bash-4.2$
```

Setup:di:compile output

```
-bash-4.2$ /opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php bin/magento setup:di:compile -vvv
Compilation was started.
Repositories code generation... 
1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 42.0 MiB

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 528384 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/dotarz.com/httpdocs/vendor/zendframework/zend-code/src/Scanner/FileScanner.php on line 36

Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.

-bash-4.2$
```

Comment: If the suggestion from Rakesh doesn't work, pay attention to the fact that PHP ran out of memory; the default memory allowance of 128M may be insufficient and can be increased in the php.ini file. Bump it up to 256M or 512M and try again. If you still get a memory error at that point and the limit given in the error message hasn't changed it will mean that you edited the wrong php.ini file or made a faulty edit; in that case identify your mistake and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute these command in the same order

```
rm -rf var/generation;
rm -rf var/cache;
rm -rf var/page_cache;
/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php bin/magento setup:di:compile;
/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy;
/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php bin/magento cache:clean;
/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php bin/magento cache:flush;
```

Answer (score -2):

After connexion CLI :

```
export PATH=/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin:$PATH
```